# Не запускается denwer

Tags: denwer

Вдруг перестал работать denwer, когда не запускаю денвер и пытаюсь зайти на localhost, то как не удивительно ошибку выдает. Но когда запускаю денвер, но при попытке зайти на localhost нечего не происходит. Просто пусная белая страничка в бруезере.

Пробовал переустановить, все тоже самое.

Хотя утром работал, все было хорошо. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А когда запускаете, что пишет в консоли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте пропинговать localhost (запустите командную строку и напишите: ping localhost или ping 127.0.0.1) Если не пингуется, то найдите в Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ файл hosts и гляньте его содержимое, должно быть что-то подобное:

```
# Всякие комменты
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.subdomain.localhost
127.0.0.1   www.subdomain.test1.ru
127.0.0.1   subdomain.localhost
................................
```